# Есть калькулятор, не могу поправить его на счет месяцев, сейчас он считает дни

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, на сайте стоит калькулятор, он считает дни (я кручу бегунок и к текущей дате скрипт прибавляет дни в зависимости от того сколько я накрутил), я хочу чтобы он считал месяцы (прибавлял кол-во месяцев которые я накрутил), а вот как поправить код в скрипте не могу понять, кто может помочь?

```
<script>
$('.checkbox-month').on('change', function(index) {
    $( ".checkbox-month" ).each(function( index ) {
        this.checked = false;
        console.log(index);
    });
    this.checked = true;
});
$(function () {
    $("[name=phone]").mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99")
    var handlePrice = $("#priceHandle");
    var handleTime = $("#timeHandle");
    var today = new Date();
    Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
        var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
        dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
        return dat;
    };
    function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }
    var dat = new Date();
    $('.review__slider').slick({
        dots: true
    });

    $('.partners-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        dots: false
    });


    $('.investition-slider__slider').slick({
        dots: false,
        prevArrow: false,
        nextArrow: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000
    });
    var price_slider = $("#slider_price").slider({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            handlePrice.text(ui.value);
            $('.sum').text(ui.value);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            handlePrice.text(ui.value);

            var currentvalue = ui.value;
            $('.sum').text(currentvalue);

            var percent =  currentvalue / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
            var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
            var toBack = Math.round(result+ui.value);
            $('.returnSum').text(toBack);


            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            handlePrice.text(ui.value);

            var currentvalue = ui.value;
            $('.sum').text(currentvalue);

            var percent =  currentvalue / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
            var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
            var toBack = Math.round(result+ui.value);
            $('.returnSum').text(toBack);


            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
        },
        value: <?php echo $options['min_money'];?>,
        min: <?php echo $options['min_money'];?>,
        max: <?php echo $options['max_money'];?>,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        step: <?php echo $options['money_step'] ?>,
        animate: true
    });

    var time_slider = $("#slider_time").slider({
        create: function (event, ui) {
            handleTime.text(ui.value);

            var currentvalue = ui.value;
            var currentValueTime = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
            var percent =  currentValueTime / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
            var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
            var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('.returnSum').text(toBack);
            $('.timeHandle').text(currentvalue);

            $('.backDay').text( formatDate(dat.addDays($(this).slider('value'))) );
            $('#returnTerm').val($(this).slider('value'));
            $('#returnDay').val( formatDate(dat.addDays(<?php echo '' . $options['minDays'];?>)) );
            $("#amount").val($('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
        },
        change: function (event, ui) {
            handleTime.text(ui.value);

            var currentvalue = ui.value;

            var currentValueTime = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
            var percent =  currentValueTime / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
            var result = percent * ui.value;
            var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('.returnSum').text(toBack);
            $('.timeHandle').text(currentvalue);

            $('.backDay').text( formatDate(dat.addDays(ui.value)) );
            $('#returnTerm').val(ui.value);
            $('#returnDay').val( formatDate(dat.addDays(ui.value)) );
            $("#amount").val($('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
        },
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            handleTime.text(ui.value);

            var currentvalue = ui.value;

            var currentValueTime = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
            var percent =  currentValueTime / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
            var result = percent * ui.value;
            var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('.returnSum').text(toBack);
            $('.timeHandle').text(currentvalue);

            $('.backDay').text( formatDate(dat.addDays(ui.value)) );
            $('#returnTerm').val($(this).slider('value'));
            $('#returnDay').val( formatDate(dat.addDays(ui.value)) );
            $("#amount").val($('#slider_price').slider('value'));
            $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
        },
        value: <?php echo $options['minDays'];?>,
        min: <?php echo $options['minDays'];?>,
        max: <?php echo $options['maxDays'];?>,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        step: <?php echo $options['days_step'] ?>,
        animate: true
    });

    $('.price_minus').click(function() {
        price_slider.slider('value', price_slider.slider('value') - <?php echo $options['money_step'] ?> );
        var currentvalue = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
        $('.sum').text(currentvalue);

        var percent =  currentvalue / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
        var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
        var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('.returnSum').text(toBack);

        $("#amount").val($(this).slider('value'));
        $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);

    });


    $('.price_plus').click(function() {
        price_slider.slider('value', price_slider.slider('value') + <?php echo $options['money_step'] ?> );
        var currentvalue = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
        $('.sum').text(currentvalue);

        var percent =  currentvalue / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
        var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
        var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('.returnSum').text(toBack);

        $("#amount").val($(this).slider('value'));
        $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
    });

    $('.day_minus').click(function() {
        time_slider.slider('value', time_slider.slider('value') - <?php echo $options['days_step'] ?> );
        var currentvalue = $("#slider_time").slider('value');

        var currentValueTime = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
        var percent =  currentValueTime / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
        var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
        var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('.returnSum').text(toBack);
        $('.timeHandle').text(currentvalue);

        $('.backDay').text( formatDate(dat.addDays(time_slider.slider('value'))) );
        $('#returnTerm').val($('#slider_time').slider('value'));
        $('#returnDay').val( formatDate(dat.addDays($(this).slider('value'))) );
        $("#amount").val($('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);

    });

    $('.day_plus').click(function() {
        time_slider.slider('value', time_slider.slider('value') + <?php echo $options['days_step'] ?> );
        var currentvalue = $("#slider_time").slider('value');

        var currentValueTime = $('#slider_price').slider('value');
        var percent =  currentValueTime / 100 * <?php echo $options['percent'] ?>;
        var result = percent * $('#slider_time').slider('value');
        var toBack = Math.round(result+$('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('.returnSum').text(toBack);
        $('.timeHandle').text(currentvalue);

        $('.backDay').text( formatDate(dat.addDays(time_slider.slider('value'))) );
        $('#returnTerm').val($('#slider_time').slider('value'));
        $('#returnDay').val( formatDate(dat.addDays($(this).slider('value'))) );
        $("#amount").val($('#slider_price').slider('value'));
        $('#amountReturn').val(toBack);
    });
});
```

Заранее Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Прикрепите нормальный снипет, где вашим творением можно воспользоваться и наглядно увидеть ваш вопрос

Comment: снипет не получается, там еще php код потому что есть, могу ссылку на сайт показать и там калькулятор сразу увидите https://salam24.kg/ru/calculate-ru/
сейчас должно быть видно